# Get URL of the image that is the first result in google images

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, google-image-search

I have multiple keywords in an excel file, I am looking for a way to get the image URL of the first google image result on another cell in this excel file,

For Example

if my cell A1 contains "tomato"
I want cell A2 to display "https://seeds-gallery.com/4963-large_default/novosadski-jabucar-tomato-450-seeds.jpg" which is the image URL of the first result that shows up on Google Images

Can someone please help me out

Comment: please use [edit] to include your current best attempt and explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in VBA using something like the following;

```
Public Sub InsertPicturesFromWeb()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim imgElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim imgElement As HTMLImg
    Dim aElement As HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim N As Integer, I As Integer
    Dim Url As String, Url2 As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim M, sImageSearchString
    
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For I = 1 To LastRow
        Url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(I, 1) & "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&rnd=1"
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        
        With IE
            .Visible = False
            .Navigate Url
            
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Set HTMLdoc = .document
                
                Set imgElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("IMG")
                
                N = 1
                For Each imgElement In imgElements
                    If InStr(imgElement.src, sImageSearchString) Then
                        If imgElement.ParentNode.nodeName = "A" Then
                            Set aElement = imgElement.ParentNode
                            
                            Url2 = imgElement.src
                            N = N + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                
                Call GetShapeFromWeb(Url2, Cells(I, 2))
                
                IE.Quit
                Set IE = Nothing
            End With
        Next I
End Sub

Sub GetShapeFromWeb(strShpUrl As String, rngTarget As Range)
   With rngTarget.Parent
      .Pictures.Insert strShpUrl
      .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Left = rngTarget.Left
      .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Top = rngTarget.Top
   End With
End Sub
```